# I am confused with the battery life specifications of the Fujifilm X-T200 on it's official specs page

Tags: battery, fujifilm

So, my question is this. The Fujifilm X-T200's specifications website https://fujifilm-x.com/en-us/products/cameras/x-t200/specifications/ mentions individual movie recording times of 4k, full HD and HD, with different aspect ratios. Also, at the end, there is some more information about battery, that has actual battery life of movie capture and continuance battery life of movie capture. The last two values are wildly different from the individual recording times provided earlier in the specs list(4k30P time is 80 minutes and FHD60P time is 95 minutes). Could someone please tell me how long the camera actually lasts when shooting in Full HD at 60fps?

Comment: Battery performance estimates are just that: estimates. Real-world usage can vary greatly from one user to the next based on specific camera settings and usage patterns. Some manufacturers tend to estimate a "worse case" scenario and real world usage is often much better. Others tend to use pie-in-the-sky estimates, where anything that could possibly consume more battery power is turned off while testing.

Comment: Basic things like the temperature of the location you are in wildly changes battery life as well.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my understanding you have 95 minutes continuous FHD/60fps recording. If you activate face detection, continuous autofocus (if available) and so on options this time may reduce significantly.

But be aware, as this is still camera, you are limited for one records to 29 minutes 59 seconds.

Comment: So what happens after reaching the 29-minute limit? Can I record after that? And is there a way to bypass the limit? And, since it says continuous recording, shouldn't I be able to record for 95 minutes? Sorry, I am completely new to photography.

Comment: @da_vinci_3864, after 29 minute the camera just stop recording and close the file. If you press the record button again it create new video record for another 30 minutes. To record more than 30 minutes you need videocamera or specific still cameras which can record longer time.

Comment: Could you recommend a camera at a similar price point without the recording limit?

Comment: @da_vinci_3864, first your question is more appropriate to be here: https://video.stackexchange.com/ Also equipment recommendations are not acceptable here. I can hardly image use case where you need continuous record for more than 30 minutes, you can always merge them in post. And videocameras can cost from few hundred to 100k USD/EURO...